# Importing webPart with PowerShell through command line versus PS1 script behaves differently

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powershell, csom, script

If I execute the following through a PowerShell console (ran manually) I am able to get the webParts to work correctly:

```
$list = $context.web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages du site")
$context.Load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$pages = $list.RootFolder.Files
$context.Load($pages)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$page = $list.RootFolder.Files | Where {$_.Name -eq "Accueil.aspx"}
$context.Load($page)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$wpm = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared")
$context.Load($wpm)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$webParts = $wpm.WebParts
$context.Load($webParts)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$xmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\table_matieres.webpart" -Raw
$xmlDocument1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\flux_site.dwp" -Raw

$wpManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$importWP = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlDocument)
$importWP1 = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlDocument1)

$wp = $wpManager.AddWebPart($importWP.WebPart,"wpz",0)
$wp1 = $wpManager.AddWebPart($importWP1.WebPart,"wpz",0)
$context.Load($wp)
$context.Load($wp1)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

However, if I run the exact same commands in a PS1 script, I get the following error:

> The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part
>   description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed
>   XML.

There must be a valid reason for this, which I was not able to find yet (after searching around the web). I did try to change some lines to add "[xml]" such as:

```
[xml]$xmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\table_matieres.webpart" -Encoding UTF8
[xml]$xmlDocument1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\flux_site.dwp" -Encoding UTF8
```

Or

```
$xmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\table_matieres.webpart")
$xmlDocument1 = [xml](Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\flux_site.dwp")
```

But I am still always getting the same error message.

I suspect that a PS1 script validates the webParts differently (or the XML files).

What needs to be changed for the same commands to work in a PS1 script please?

Thank you for your time and help, it's always appreciated.